# Is there a way to convert Hibernate XML mappings to Annotational Mappings?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations, hbmxml

Is there a possibility to convert my existing `hbm.xml` mapping to annotational mapping?

The goal is to get through an automatic mechanism all my xml mappings to annotational Mappings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting from Hibernate hbm.xml to annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962231/converting-from-hibernate-hbm-xml-to-annotations)

Comment: Indeed the advice in that link is the least bad; reverse engineer the entities new from the database schema and then manually go through them to fix all the annotations to what you need them to be. Its boring work, but nobody ever said that programming was all fun and games.

Comment: We wrote a tool to automate all the boring parts: [You can find it here](https://github.com/SchweizerischeBundesbahnen/hibernate_hbm2annotation).