# Switch from JPA Hibernate to JPA Eclipselink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I am currently working on a project that requires JPA-annotated Java-classes to persist into the database with Eclipselink. Unfortunately, no negotiation is possible here from my side.

Now, we have a dependency to classes we need to persist into a very complex database, where the Java-classes are also very complex.
We are talking about hundreds of classes and thousands of attributes.
These classes from the dependency come from another project, that uses **hibernate **to persist their data into the database. They accordingly provide the fitting hibernate **config files**, that map the Java-classes to the database tables (non-trivial).

I am looking for an automated way to translate these hibernate config files into the dependency-classes, so I end up with JPA-annotated classes that Eclipselink can work with.

Or is there a way that Eclipselink could work with these hibernate files?

Thank you in advance kind community!

One approach we follow right now, is to rebuild the database from the hibernate files and then create JPA-annotated Java-classes so we can persist them via Eclipselink.

Unfortunately, this method requires time-consuming labour, such that we would need to map the data from the dependecy classes to the newly generated JPA-annotated classes.

I wonder, if we can skip the mapping part and really use the hibernate files to transition to Eclipselink.

Comment: I'm assuming that when you say "fitting hibernate config files" you are not talking about JPA `orm.xml` files inside `META-INF` folder, right? Can you provide an sample of these files you're talking about?

Comment: Hi @MauricioBuffon yes you are right. I am talking about the MyClass.cfg.xml files, that define the mappings to the database from my respective java classes

Comment: Other products, EclipseLink included, do not work with native hibernate configuration files, though you could write your own reader to make it happen - but if that is worth it depends on how many classes are involved and how much you can pick up from the EclipseLink unit tests that dynamically modify the config at runtime. If you do, EclipseLink has ways to write out its project mappings as orm.xml (or non-jpa parts into an eclipselink-orm.xml, at least allowing an easier time if you want to switch again).

Comment: IDEs and other tools can generate entities from tables, so you might try that to reduce the migration workload, and then figure out what specific customizations from the hibernate files are still needed to add in manually.

Comment: I found this rather old question, but with a relatively recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962231/converting-from-hibernate-hbm-xml-to-annotations. Maybe the project referenced in the answer can help.